# C# Updating table adapter doesn't update DB

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, oledb, strongly-typed-dataset

I'm facing a problem with updating DB with OleDBCommandBuilder and typed dataset. When I'm editing my database with prepared panel, after update I see changes take place in DataGridView. But these changes are temporary, beacause when I restart my application changes are replaced back with original information from database. Can anyone see a problem with code given below?

```
var row = this.dataGridViewProducts.SelectedRows[0];
        DataRowView rowView = row.DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
        ProductsRow productRow = rowView.Row as ProductsRow;
        if (row != null)
        {
            ProductForm formEdit = new ProductForm(ref productRow);
            bool success = false;
            while (success == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    formEdit.ShowDialog();
                    if (this.productsTableAdapter1.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                        this.productsTableAdapter1.Connection.Open();
                    var changes = nwindDataSet1.Products.GetChanges();
                    if (changes != null)
                    {
                        OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(productsTableAdapter1.Adapter);
                        productsTableAdapter1.Adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
                        productsTableAdapter1.Adapter.Update(changes);
                        nwindDataSet1.Products.AcceptChanges();
                    }
                    success = true;
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(error.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try read documentation
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.update(v=vs.110).aspx 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand(v=vs.110).aspx
Make shure that you have assign `UpdateCommand` property of `DataAdapter`
Also check if there any rows in `changes`

Comment: Ok, let's figureout why =)